# How do I get disconnected networkdrives in Powershell?

Tags: shell, powershell, mapping, network-drive, net-use

I need to get all mapped networkdrives, even the ones who are currently disconnected. I tried it with `Get-PSDrive` but that only shows the ones that are currently connected. 
It is possible get all mapped networkdrives with `net use` but I can´t reuse the output (I need to save the letter and the path).

Comment: Disconnected Network drives show in the Users registry: `Get-ChildItem hkcu:\network`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the status of network drives from the Users registry using:

```
Get-ChildItem hkcu:\network
```

To access these reg entries you need to use `Get-ItemProperty`, you can build a PSObject to hold the properties to make this nicer:

```
Get-ChildItem hkcu:\network | %{            
    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty Drive $_.name.Replace('HKEY_CURRENT_USER\network\','')
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Path (Get-ItemProperty (Join-Path hkcu:\network $_.name.split('\')[-1]) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty RemotePath)
    [array]$mapped += $obj
}
```

Example properties:

```
PS> $mapped

Drive Path          
----- ----          
Y     \\server1\share
Z     \\server2\hidden$
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don´t really get what this code does... So how do I acces just the "Y" or just the "\\server2\hidden$" for example? Is there a way to iterate through it? (I am really new to Powershell)

Comment: Yes you can iterate through the object, here's a blog on the subject: https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/iterating-through-collections-powershells-foreach-loops

Answer (score 3):

while the HKCU path solution posted by James C. is likely a better solution, you CAN get the output of `net use` into objects. lookee ...

```
net use |
    Select-Object -SkipLast 2 |
    Select-Object -Skip 6 |
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\s{2,}', ', '} |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Status, DriveLetter, UNC_Path, Network |
    Select-Object -Property DriveLetter, UNC_Path
```

hope that helps,
lee

Comment: Nice one +1, easier: `(net use) -replace '\s{2,}', ',' |sls '\\\\'|ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Status, DriveLetter, UNC_Path, Network`

Comment: @LotPings - i keep forgetting about Select-String. matching on the double slash is likely faster, too! [*grin*]